# Error — Unhandled exception type Exception

Tags: java, exception

I'm currently creating a plugin for a game and for some unknown reason, I'm getting an error when I initialize the variable `dbManager`.

The variable is the second one that's being initialized and it's at the top of my class.
The line giving the error is:

```
static DBManager dbManager = DBManager.getInstance();
```

[The whole class can be found here.](https://github.com/Spedwards/SlimeWarns/blob/master/src/me/pinkslime/SlimeWarns/MySQL.java#L15)

It invokes [DBManager](https://github.com/MrMysteri0us/DBManager).

I tried wrapping it in try, catch blocks but that in itself gave it's own error. Eclipse isn't giving any auto correct suggestions either.

The error I'm getting is `Unhandled exception type Exception`. As this is a plugin, I'm currently unable to test this code to get any stacktrace.

What can I do to fix the error.

Comment: @AliAmiri It's in the title. I was meant to include it in the question but forgot.

Comment: no I mean stacktrace or anything better than those 3 words in title!

Comment: @AliAmiri It's a plugin that I'm unable to test. There is no stacktrace. Plus it's 4 words.

Comment: Ok, from what I see and you provided it is because getInstance throws exception, checkout my answer and let me if it is your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a static block to initialize this variable:

```
static DBManager dbManager;

static {
    try {
        dbManager = DBManager.getInstance();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unable to geta DBManager instance", e);
    }
}
```

I would not use a library which uses the raw Exception class to signal errors, though. Using non-final static fields as you're doing is another design smell.

Answer (score 0):

Although I cant see the code from `DBManager`, this error says that there is `unhandled exception` this means `DBManager.getInstance()` throws exception and you could not use it like what you did in the link. you must handle the exception. It is better to get instance in your constructor and handle the exception ( at least with a `try/catch`) in there.